# How to keep drawn shapes after the form is refreshed?

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I am trying to create a small paint application in Visual Studio 2015. My project falls into the category of Windows Form Applications. I have the following problem:

```
 private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (a == 1)
        {
            if (r == 1 || el == 1)
            {
                int x = Math.Min(inX, e.X);
                int y = Math.Min(inY, e.Y);
                int width = Math.Max(inX, e.X) - Math.Min(inX, e.X);
                int height = Math.Max(inY, e.Y) - Math.Min(inY, e.Y);
                rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
                Refresh();
            }
            else if (l == 1)
            {
                ep = e.Location;
                Refresh();
            }
            else
            {
                ep = e.Location;
                g = this.CreateGraphics();
                g.DrawLine(p, sp, ep);
                sp = ep;
            }
        }
    }
```

This part of  my codes creates a Rectangular (**2nd** if), a line segment(**3rd** if) and just a line. It works pretty much the same as MS Paint; the rectangular or the line segment isn not completed until the user releases the left mouse click (Mouse up). But when a rectangular is finally made when I try again to create another one, the form refreshes ( **Refresh();** ) and I lose all the previous drawn rectangulars or lines. I tried replacing **Refresh();** with **Invalidate(rect);** and **Update();**, but I do not get the result I want.

Instead, I get this:

[image]

Comment: Immediate (like GDI in your case) vs Retained mode explanation - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684178(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should do all your drawing to a separate `Bitmap` "buffer" that you keep around.  Draw your shapes to that bitmap, then when the screen actually needs to be updated, draw the buffer to the screen.

Also, anytime you call `Graphics.FromImage` you need to remember to `Dispose`, or it will leak resources like crazy.

**Incredibly simple example**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DrawExample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private Bitmap _canvas; //This is the offscreen drawing buffer
        private Point _anchor; //The start point for click-drag operations
        private Rectangle? _ghost;
        private Brush _ghostBrush;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _ghostBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 200, 255)); //This creates a slightly blue, transparent brush for the ghost preview
            ResizeCanvas();
        }

        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ResizeCanvas();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Resizes the offscreen bitmap to match the current size of the window, it preserves what is currently in the bitmap.
        /// </summary>
        private void ResizeCanvas()
        {
            Bitmap tmp = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tmp))
            {
                g.Clear(Color.White);
                if (_canvas != null)
                {
                    g.DrawImage(_canvas, 0, 0);
                    _canvas.Dispose();
                }
            }
            _canvas = tmp;
        }

        private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                _anchor = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            }
        }
        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                _ghost = new Rectangle(_anchor.X, _anchor.Y, e.X - _anchor.X, e.Y - _anchor.Y);
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                //Create a Graphics for the offscreen bitmap
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(_canvas))
                {
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(_anchor.X, _anchor.Y, e.X - _anchor.X, e.Y - _anchor.Y);
                    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, rect);
                    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect);
                }

                _ghost = null;

                //This queues up a redraw call for the form
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            if (_ghost.HasValue)
            {
                using (Bitmap tmp = new Bitmap(_canvas))
                {
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tmp))
                    {
                        g.FillRectangle(_ghostBrush, _ghost.Value);
                        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, _ghost.Value);

                        e.Graphics.DrawImage(tmp, 0, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(_canvas, 0, 0);
            }
        }


        //This stops the flickering
        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //Do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer. I am searching for a bitmap buffer tutorial, but I can't seem to find something useful and thorough. Do you have a guide in mind?

Comment: I added a few notes to my answer for you.

Comment: Here is an MSDN example showing more complete code.  It doesn't use the persistent buffer approach that both David and I suggested though.  But it does give a good example of creating and drawing to an off screen bitmap. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172506(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: As you are creating a drawing program, one of the trickier issues you will have to deal with is how to handle the "preview ghost" as the user moves the mouse and resizes rectangles and other shapes.  None of these techniques will directly solve that, and it's a fairly complex topic.  You will need some combination of differed drawing to an offscreen bitmap, and the immediate drawing similar to what you are doing now.

Comment: Your notes really seem very helpful and detailed. But being in the process of learning C#, I do not understand everything. I found this guide [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404307(v=vs.110).aspx) in msdn's site. Is this the proper way to create a bitmap method? Thanks again for your patience!!

Comment: Yes, that code will create a 200 by 100 offscreen bitmap for drawing. You will probably want to adjust the size based on the .Height and .width properties of whatever control you end up targeting in the end though.  It probably isn't the "best" way to go about it though.  This really is a fairly complex topic overall, with a lot of advanced stuff to learn if you want to pull it all off correctly.  There are a lot of subtitles with optimizing things and avoiding flickering.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is truly a very complex and interesting topic. I appreciate your help!!

Comment: I've updated my answer with an incredibly simple example.

Comment: This is really an incredibly simple example. It is very informative and it solved all my basic questions for bitmap. Thank you very much!!

Comment: I was bored enough that I updated the example again.  This one fixes all the flickering, and draws the ghost preview.  Enjoy!

Comment: For some reason I can't draw the rectangle in both sides. What  I mean is that if I move the mouse while holding down its left button to the left side of the canvas, the rectangle disappears. Any ideas?

Comment: When you draw a "backwards" rectangle (from right to left or bottom to top), you end up with a rectangle that has a negative width or height.  GDI doesn't support that.  You have to "normalize" the rectangle before drawing it so that it always starts at the top left and goes down and right.  Basically, if width is negative, move the X to the left and multiply the width by -1. same idea for the height. You end up with a rectangle that has the exact same shape and position, but all its properties are positive.

Comment: I used this code and worked:

    `x = Math.Min(_anchor.X, e.X)`
     `y = Math.Min(_anchor.Y, e.X)`
     `width = Math.Abs(_anchor.X - e.X)`
     `height = Math.Abs(_anchor.Y - e.Y)`
    

What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

You are drawing directly onto the form's drawing surface. That surface is not persistent. It lasts until the next paint cycle.

Instead you should:

1. Draw to an offscreen bitmap.
2. Draw that bitmap onto, for instance, a picture box control. Or paint it directly onto the form's drawing surface in its `Paint` event.

Comment: Or any other kind of persisting the model of the picture - WPF object tree, custom tree/list of objects (like array of rectangles).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan First of all, thanks for such an immediate answer. It seems to me easier your 2nd proposition. But if I create a picturebox in my form, can I then draw a bitmap inside it. I am still learning, so thanks for your patience.

Comment: A picture box would work. I think though that I'd be looking for a Paint event either on the form, or some other control. It depends a little on the design of the rest of your app. Essentially though you need to be able to paint your content when asked, in an event driven fashion. That's they key thing to learn.